# Remove duplicated from two files and merge the unique ones

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I Have two big text files, checksums_1.txt and checksums_2.txt, I want to parse these files and remove duplication between them and merge the unique lines in one file.

Each file have the following structure for each line.

size, md5, path

Example: Checksums_1.txt

```
9565, a4fs614as6fas4fa4s46fsaf1, /mnt/app/1tier/2tier/filename.exe
9565, a4fs614as6fas4fa4s46fsaf1, /mnt/app/1tier/2tier/filename2.exe
```

Example: Checksums_2.txt

```
9565, a4fs614as6fas4fa4s46fsaf1, /mnt/temp/1tier/2tier/filename.exe
9565, a4fs614as6fas4fa4s46fsaf1, /mnt/temp/1tier/2tier/filename2.exe
9565, a4fs614as6fas4fa4s46fsaf1, /mnt/temp/1tier/2tier/newfile.exe
```

The section that have to be used to check between the checksums_1.txt and checksums_2.txt is after the mountpoint /mnt/app/ and /mnt/temp/, In other words, from the start of each line to the end of the mountpoint /mnt/temp/ or /mnt/app/ will be ignored.

The data inside checksums_1.txt is more important, so if a a duplicated is found the line in checksums_1.txt must be moved to the merged file.

Part of Checksums_1.txt

```
1058,b8203a236b4f15316e516165a6546666,/mnt/app/Certificados/ca.crt
2694,8a815adefde4fa0c263e74832b15de64,/mnt/app/Certificados/ca.db.certs/01.pem
136,77bf2e5313dbaac4df76a4b72df2e2ad,/mnt/app/Certificados/ca.db.index
```

Part of Checksums_2.txt

```
1058,b8203a236b4f1531616318284202c9e6,/mnt/temp/Certificados/ca.crt
3,72b2ac90f7f3ff075a937d6be8fc3dc3,/mnt/temp/Certificados/ca.db.serial 
2694,8a815adefde4fa0c263e74832b15de64,/mnt/temp/Certificados/ca.db.certs/01.pem
136,77bf2e5313dbaac4df76a4b72df2e2ad,/mnt/temp/Certificados/ca.db.index
```

Example of the merged file

```
1058,b8203a236b4f15316e516165a6546666,/mnt/app/Certificados/ca.crt 
3,72b2ac90f7f3ff075a937d6be8fc3dc3,/mnt/temp/Certificados/ca.db.serial 
2694,8a815adefde4fa0c263e74832b15de64,/mnt/app/Certificados/ca.db.certs/01.pem
136,77bf2e5313dbaac4df76a4b72df2e2ad,/mnt/app/Certificados/ca.db.index
```

Comment: OK, give us couple more examples, and also give us example how the output should look like

Comment: Ive edited and now have more examples and a better explanation

Comment: Is the part "/mnt/MASTER/examplepath/exemplefile.doc" in the master file the master key for the line?

Comment: The section that I want to check between the files is after the mount point /mnt/app/ or /mnt/temp/, I've edited it again, so just the /1tier/2tier/filename.exe will be checked.

Comment: One more question: is the mountpoint *per file* a single one?

Comment: Yes, for checksums_1.txt is /mnt/app and for checksums_2.txt is /mnt/temp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming both files are not *huge*, the python script below will do the job as well.

#### How it works

Both files are read by the script. The lines in *file_1* (the file that has precedence) is split by the directory you entered for the file in the head section (in your example `/mnt/app/`).

Subsequently, the lines in file_1 are written to the output file (the merged file). At the same time, lines from file_2 are removed from the line list *if* the identifying string (the section after the mount point) occurs in the line.
Finally, the "remaining" lines of file_2 (of which no dupe exist in file_1) are written to the output file as well. The result:

file_1:

```
1058,b8203a236b4f15316e516165a6546666,/mnt/app/Certificados/ca.crt
2694,8a815adefde4fa0c263e74832b15de64,/mnt/app/Certificados/ca.db.certs/01.pem
136,77bf2e5313dbaac4df76a4b72df2e2ad,/mnt/app/Certificados/ca.db.index
```

file_2:

```
1058,b8203a236b4f15316e516165a6546666,/mnt/app/Certificados/ca.crt
3,72b2ac90f7f3ff075a937d6be8fc3dc3,/mnt/temp/Certificados/ca.db.serial
2694,8a815adefde4fa0c263e74832b15de64,/mnt/app/Certificados/ca.db.certs/01.pem
136,77bf2e5313dbaac4df76a4b72df2e2ad,/mnt/app/Certificados/ca.db.index
```

merged:

```
1058,b8203a236b4f15316e516165a6546666,/mnt/app/Certificados/ca.crt
2694,8a815adefde4fa0c263e74832b15de64,/mnt/app/Certificados/ca.db.certs/01.pem
136,77bf2e5313dbaac4df76a4b72df2e2ad,/mnt/app/Certificados/ca.db.index
3,72b2ac90f7f3ff075a937d6be8fc3dc3,/mnt/temp/Certificados/ca.db.serial
```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#---set the path to file1, file2 and the mountpoint used in file1 below
f1 = "/path/to/file_1"; m_point = "/mnt/app"; f2 = "/path/to/file_2"
merged = "/path/to/merged_file"
#---
lines1 = [(l, l.split(m_point)[-1]) for l in open(f1).read().splitlines()]
lines2 = [l for l in open(f2).read().splitlines()]

for l in lines1:
    open(merged, "a+").write(l[0]+"\n")
    for line in [line for line in lines2 if l[1] in line]:
            lines2.remove(line)

for l in lines2:
    open(merged, "a+").write(l+"\n")
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `merge.py`
2. in the head section of the script, set the paths to `f1` (`file_1`), `f2`, the path to the merging file and the mountpoint as mentioned in `file_1`.
3. Run it by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/merge.py
   ```

#### *Edit*

Or a tiny bit shorter:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#---set the path to file1, file2 and the mountpoint used in file1 below
f1 = "/path/to/file_1"; m_point = "/mnt/app"; f2 = "/path/to/file_2"
merged = "/path/to/merged_file"
#---
lines = lambda f: [l for l in open(f).read().splitlines()]
lines1 = lines(f1); lines2 = lines(f2); checks = [l.split(m_point)[-1] for l in lines1]
for item in sum([[l for l in lines2 if c in l] for c in checks], []):
    lines2.remove(item)
for item in lines1+lines2:
    open(merged, "a+").write(item+"\n")
```

Comment: When ran the command it output this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merge.py", line 7, in <module>
    lines1 = [(l, l.split(m_point)[1]) for l in open(f1).read().splitlines()]
  File "merge.py", line 7, in <listcomp>
    lines1 = [(l, l.split(m_point)[1]) for l in open(f1).read().splitlines()]
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @AndréM.Faria I just rechecked, ran the script again, are you sure you didn't mix up the paths? f1 is the one with the` m_point = "/mnt/app"` if the mountpoint does not exist in the lines, you will get an indexerror, since the split("/mnt/app") will result in one section.

Comment: @AndréM.Faria do you manage?

Comment: `f1 = "/mnt/storage/temp/checksums_1.txt"; m_point = "/mnt/app"; f2 = "/mnt/storage/temp/checksum_2.txt"
merged = "/mnt/storage/temp/merged.txt"`

Comment: The error occur with sudo.

Comment: @AndréM.Faria What can I say? the error message you mention says one or more lines do not have an index 1 when split by the mountpoint. That means either not in all of the lines the mountpoint occurs, or you mix up file1/file2. From here I cannot look into the files and cannot check what you are doing exactly. Please check file 1 if there are lines without te mountpoint.

Comment: If you not said "That means either not in all of the lines the mountpoint occurs"... In the head of the file have some comment lines, I've removed it and the script is running

Comment: @AndréM.Faria AHA, I edited the script to "immunize" it to those lines. They will be copied unchanged now to the merged file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use python (therefore if performance is not an issue), what you want can be achieved with the following script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import csv
import re

mountpoint1 = "/mnt/app/"
mountpoint2 = "/mnt/temp/"

if (len(sys.argv) != 4):
    print('Usage: {} <input file 1> <input file 2> <output file>'.format(sys.argv[0]))
    exit(1)

inputFileName1 = sys.argv[1]
inputFileName2 = sys.argv[2]
outputFileName = sys.argv[3]

# We place entries from both input files in the same dictionary
# The key will be the filename stripped of the mountpoint
# The value will be the whole line
fileDictionary = dict()

# First we read entries from file2, so that those
# from file2 will later overwrite them when needed
with open(inputFileName2) as inputFile2:
    csvReader = csv.reader(inputFile2)
    for row in csvReader:
        if len(row) == 3:
            # The key will be the filename stripped of the mountpoint
            key = re.sub(mountpoint2, '', row[2])
            # The value will be the whole line
            fileDictionary[key] = ','.join(row)

# Entries from file1 will overwrite those from file2
with open(inputFileName1) as inputFile1:
    csvReader = csv.reader(inputFile1)
    for row in csvReader:
        if len(row) == 3:
            # The key will be the filename stripped of the mountpoint
            key = re.sub(mountpoint1, '', row[2])
            # The value will be the whole line
            fileDictionary[key] = ','.join(row)

# Write all the entries to the output file
with open(outputFileName, 'w') as outputFile:
    for key in fileDictionary:
        outputFile.write(fileDictionary[key])
        outputFile.write('\n')
```

Simply save the script as `merge-checksums.py`, give it execution permission

```
chmod u+x merge-checksums.py
```

and run it as:

```
./merge-checksums.py Checksums_1.txt Checksums_2.txt out.txt
```

Comment: It worked using the examples I've mentioned above, but with the real files it not worked.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Did it produce any error or was there something wrong with the output?

Comment: I was trying to edit my comment to add the answer, the output was the sum of the first file with the second file, I will change my ask and add part of the real file, because I thin is that the problem.

Comment: Your script worked, was the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

The `bash` version (with `awk` and `grep`):

```
#!/bin/bash

filename1="$1"
filename2="$2"

keys=$(awk -F'/' '{ for(i=4;i<NF;i++) printf "%s",$i "/"; if (NF) printf "%s",$NF; printf "\n"}' "$filename1" "$filename2" | awk '{gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"")};1' | sort -u)

while read -r key
do
    match=$(grep "$key" "$filename1")
    if [ "$match" != "" ]
    then
        echo "$match"
    else
        grep "$key" "$filename2"
    fi
done <<< "$keys"
```

`Checksums_1.txt`

```
9565, 1111111111111111111111111, /mnt/app/1tier/2tier/filename.exe
9565, 0000000000000000000000000, /mnt/app/1tier/2tier/filename2.exe
```

`Checksums_2.txt`

```
9565, 2222222222222222222222222, /mnt/temp/1tier/2tier/filename.exe
9565, 0000000000000000000000000, /mnt/temp/1tier/2tier/filename2.exe
9565, 3333333333333333333333333, /mnt/temp/1tier/2tier/newfile.exe
```

*Run with*

```
./merge_checksum Checksums_1.txt Checksums_2.txt > Checksums_3.txt
```

`Checksums_3.txt`

```
9565, 1111111111111111111111111, /mnt/app/1tier/2tier/filename.exe
9565, 0000000000000000000000000, /mnt/app/1tier/2tier/filename2.exe
9565, 3333333333333333333333333, /mnt/temp/1tier/2tier/newfile.exe
```

*Or with **interchanged** input files*

```
./merge_checksum Checksums_2.txt Checksums_1.txt > Checksums_3.txt
```

`Checksums_3.txt`

```
9565, 0000000000000000000000000, /mnt/temp/1tier/2tier/filename2.exe
9565, 2222222222222222222222222, /mnt/temp/1tier/2tier/filename.exe
9565, 3333333333333333333333333, /mnt/temp/1tier/2tier/newfile.exe
```

Comment: I've tested, using the examples above and it work, but I've added at the Checksums_1.txt `9655, 0000000000000000, /mnt/app/aa/bb/cc/ti.g` and it has being ignored and not present at the Checksums_3.txt

Comment: Please test it again. I have the desired output, without that I had to make a change in the script. Copy the script again. The original version was different. This line is important: `keys=$(awk -F'/' '{ for(i=4;i<NF;i++) printf "%s",$i "/"; if (NF) printf "%s",$NF; printf "\n"}' "$filename1" "$filename2" | sort -u)`

Comment: I've copied it again, it's working, but with the real files its generated a file with the sum of both files, as with the python script.

Comment: Then you should use better examples. Obviously, your examples are significantly different from your actual files.

Comment: I've edited the ask with real part of the files, sorry.

Comment: What is this: `<< MD5 Diff from above` a comment in the original files?

Comment: Is a comment that isnt present in original files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23926/discussion-between-a-b-and-andre-m-faria).

Comment: Worked now, ive deleted the comments at the top of file